# How can I change my local image to blob file type in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

I want to change my local image into blob file type. How can I do it with **react-native-fs**. 
This is what I tried below

```
RNFS.readFile('../../assets/imgs/profile.jpg', 'base64')
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res);
      alert("res");
});
```

This is what I'm trying so far but it gives me a warning - "
no such file or directory, open '../../assets/imgs/profile.jpg'

[image: Warning]

Answer (score 0):

You can use rn-fetch-blob library

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this you are going to access the system directory.

```
../../assets/imgs/profile.jpg
```

react-native-fs give access to the native filesystem.

the image should be placed on your mobile and give the right image path

if the image inside the document directory so you can access the document path using

```
RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/profile.jpg'
```